# Android Studio: R.class file not updating

Tags: android-studio

I am new to coding and just started working through a few online courses. With regards to the R.class file, mine does not seem to be updating. It is also not located where a lot of the other discussions seem to state. One problem I initially picked up is that my activity_main.xml file is not listed under the layout class in the R.class file either. i have tried many solutions across other questions but nothing seems to help. Any advice would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Do refactor and reload may this help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you. There is another stackoverflow question, somebody answered this : you must get rid of warnings and errors (syntax and links) in your xml files. This plus doing a clean / build project.

**Project -> Clean, and choose the option to build the project.**